# OneAPI - MKL Libraries

Tags: intel-mkl, intel-oneapi

I need to prepare a build environment which allows to compile binaries with the mkl libraries: libmkl_core.so, ...
I initially used the installation instructions from oneapi [webpage](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html).
The mkl installation installed the following libraries:
[image]

However the GLIBC in the libraries provided by the installation use a very low GLIBC version(GLIBC_2.2.5).

I saw that the mkl library has a github page so imagined I could compile the library from [source](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL).

After a lot of effort I managed to compile the code but ended up with three different libraries:
libonemkl.so, libonemkl_blas_mklgpu.so, libonemkl_blas_mklcpu.so,

I feel like there is some needed clarification here.
Is there a way to build libmkl_core.so from source using a newer compiler?

Are the required files only available via intel's one api installation?

What use are the files that I did manage to build from source?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The GLIBC in the libraries provided by the installation use a very low GLIBC version(GLIBC_2.2.5). Could you please let us know how you have verified the glibc version(GLIBC_2.2.5).

Comment: ran "strings <so library path> | grep GLIBC" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source which was mentioned by you, was just provided as wrappers which would work for CPU's and GPU's other than Intel's.
It is not a MKL code and these are just wrappers.
There is no other way to build libmkl_core.so from source using a newer compiler and the required files are only available via intel's oneAPI installation.
If you want to use MKL, you are advised to check and link using MKL link line advisor as per your application environment.

Below is the link line advisor for your reference.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html